# Calculating average per month based on month dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Using the following dataset how can I average weight for each month based on column A for dates in the format month | average weight?

[image: dataset]

Comment: In which cell @pnuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  =QUERY(A2:C100,"select month(A)+1,avg(C) group by month(A)+1  label month(A)+1 'MONTH',avg(C) 'Average of Weight'")
```

Comment: @Dharmesh SurajBali If the formula works, Mark this as answered

Comment: Wow! Thanks. That works. However I'm trying to build a monthly table by month name to plot a graph for monthly averages.

You can see the whole sheets here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pX2ntRev4Q1CFthrHcE0BqfRxKtUa78nzCgXsK4kzQs/edit?usp=sharing

I want to average weight, muscle mass and fat mass by month and plot them on the graph using a table of averages which I need the formula for.

Comment: Just like avg(C) in select. Add others too... "Select month (), avg(C),avg(D) , etc etc"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Will try these